# jQuery how to get selected index

Tags: jquery, select, indexing

I have some markup:

```
<select name="serviceID[1]" id="serviceID[1]" class="computeThisService">
<option value="" selected="selected">No Selection</option>
<option value="4">TJ5</option>
<option value="1">TJ2</option>
<option value="5">TJ1</option>
<option value="2">TJ3</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to get the selected value and this does not work:

```
  var triggerID = event.target.id; // get the id that triggered the event
  var nStart = triggerID.indexOf('[') + 1;
  var nEnd = triggerID.indexOf(']');
  j = triggerID.substring(nStart, nEnd); // get the index of the id that triggered the event

  var el = $('select option:selected', this);
  alert(el.text());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `selectedIndex`:

```
$("#serviceID\\[1\\]")[0].selectedIndex
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zKDfH/)**

Comment: I tried that too earlier and it did not work @Felix. But I'll try again

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery all you need is this -

```
$('select option:selected').text();
```

So in your case it can be

```
$('#serviceID\\[1\\] option:selected').text();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/StMd2/